# MvvmCross Xamarin.iOS Bindings: How does MVVM cross know what property to bind against?

Tags: ios, data-binding, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

So I have been experimenting with MvvmCross and I came across the following syntax to create a binding:

```
this.CreateBinding (GenerositySlider).To ((TipViewModel vm) => vm.Generosity).Apply ();
```

In that code sample, `GenerositySlider`is a `UISlider` in iOS.

I know I can specify a specific property to bind against using the `For` method. But this code works and the framework knows to bind against the `Value`property on `UISlider`.

How does MvvmCross know to bind against the `Value` property on `UISlider`?

If its defaulting to a specific value for various controls, is there documentation on what property it will default to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. Posting here incase others are curious:

MvvmCross defines classes for targets that define a default property to bind against. So for the `UISlider` scenario above, it uses the `MvxUISliderValueTargetBinding` class to determine what to bind against.

I couldn't find documentation on which property Mvx will default to for various controls, but here are all the available `TargetBinding` classes for iOS:
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/4.0/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Target